# ListRasters, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.x, arcpy

Hi I have very minimal python experience and am not sure why I am getting this type error. I am trying to perform a raster to polygon conversion with the rasters from a different workspace than the initial env.workspace. Is this possible? And how can there be a no data error in the raster2 Listasters()?

The reclassify command works fine and creates the output in the defined folder but the raster to polygon tool is what is signaling the error.

Thanks for the help I need this done for work as soon as possible.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\Script_try2.py", line 30, in <module>
    for raster2 in arcpy.ListRasters():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the code:

```
# Import arcpy module 
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out any necessary licenses 
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

#Set the workplace 
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993"

#for all files in 1993, reclassify to water only rasters 
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters(): 
    folder = r"C:\Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993\Reclass" + "\\" 
    outraster = folder + raster 
    arcpy.Reclassify_3d(raster, "Value", "1 1", outraster, "NODATA") 

#Can I set up a new env workspace to get reclassified rasters from "Reclass" folder?
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993\Reclass"

#for all files in 1993\Reclass, perform RastertoPolygon 
for raster2 in arcpy.ListRasters(): 
    folder2 = r"C:\Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993\Polygons" + "\\" 
    outraster2 = folder2 + raster2 
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster2, outraster2, "NO_SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") 

print "end Processing..."`
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can give guidance or suggestions!

Comment: `arcpy.ListRasters()` returns `None`, that’s your problem. I’m pretty sure that function expects some parameters.

Comment: Okay thanks so much.  I tried that and it says 'All' is not defined so maybe I have to define it somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arcpy.ListRasters()` doesn't take any mandatory argument, see the [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/ListRasters/03q30000005m000000/). Are you sure there are any rasters in the Reclass folder? Are they successfully created by `Reclassify_3d`? My guess is that `outraster` is not well understood as you combine single and double backslashes in the path. Instead, write `outraster = os.path.join(folder, raster)` and `import os` in the beginning of your script.

Also, the script will have trouble creating the polygons, because `raster2` is probably something like raster.tiff or raster.jpg. You're using this to name your output shapefile. If your rasters have an extension, you should trim it using e.g. `arcpy.Describe(raster).baseName`. And in any case, add `.shp` as you're saving the output in a folder.

**EDIT:**
There is a typo in the second workspace, you've forgotten the `\` after the C in `r"C:Users\mkelly\Documents\Namibia\Raster_Water\1993\Reclass"`.
The workspace is wrong so your list of rasters is empty.

What format are your rasters? The extension (e.g. `'.tiff'`) will be used in the name of the output shapefile so you have to remove it. That's what I mean by 'trim'. And you should add `'.shp'`.

Comment: Hi GISGe, thank you so much for your help.  There are rasters in the Reclass folder, I can open them and Arcmap and they look just as they should.  I also tried adding the outraster = os.path.join(folder, raster) with import os, as you suggested, but I am still getting the 'NoneType' error on the for raster2 in arcpy.ListRasters("","All") line.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by trimming the extension, but my files are 13 characters (includes path, row, year, and julian date) so I can't add any extensions or I get the error that the name is too long.  This is why I am adding the outputs to new folders instead of just adding a "_poly" extension and keeping them in the same folder as the original.  I tried the arcpy.Describe(raster).baseName and am now getting a new error

Comment: GISGe, yes that worked.  I cannot believe I missed that.  Thank you very much!!